# slick carousel slickGoTo doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I'm using the slick carousel class for a slider. 
HTML:

```
<div class="map">
  <div>
    <div class="step">
      <div class="m_left"><a href="#" class="next-slide"> nextPage</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="m_right"><img src="/bindella/images/map_tsc.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.map').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true
  });

  $('.next-slide').click(function() {
    $('.map').slickGoTo(1);
  });
});
```

The function `slickGoTo` doesn't work. What is wrong?

Comment: have you included jquery plugin files? please post whole html code here.

Comment: Yes, slik.min.js (version 1.4.0) and JQuery (Version 1.11.2). The slider itself works fine. Just the slickGoTo not..

Comment: .. just updated to slik.min.js version 1.4.1, nothing changed..

Comment: Problem solved: $('.map').slick('slickGoTo','1');

Comment: @user1272597 I love you

Answer (score 27):

Please try:

```
$('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', number);
```

Comment: Please also include **why** this solution helps answer the question. That way, the original poster and others who read your answer can understand it. Thank you!

Comment: Well just because `$('.map').slickGoTo(1);` is wrong syntax with undefined function, while `$('.map').slick('slickGoTo', 1)` works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this mate.Its a small work around

```
$('.next-slide').click(function() {
  var slider = $('.map');
  slider[0].slick.slickGoTo(parseInt(2));
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sjkdpcjo/)

Comment: Works for me. Thank you!